# How to clear angular service worker cache in all clients?

Tags: javascript, angular, caching, service-worker

First of all checked all stackoverflow Q/A and haven't found my answer.

I have Angular 13 project which always used service worker (ngsw.json + ngsw-worker.js) in production build. Later the back-end api url was changed to different one in environment.ts files and after deploy to Amazon S3 cloudfront the Front-end is still calling the the old endpoint.

Okey, so it seems that my service worker cached all files and isn't updating. I have tried updating it via swUpdate, but it just don't help because it can't see any changes so I just deleted serviceWorker :

**angular.json :**

```
"serviceWorker": false,
```

**index.html :**

```
 <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
        //returns installed service workers
        if (registrations.length) {
          for(let registration of registrations) {
            registration.unregister();
            document.location.reload();
        }
     }
  });
}
  </script>
```

Ran : `npm run prerender`

Deployed dist/browser to Amazon S3 Cloudfront which don't have any service worker file and It should delete any used service worker in all client browsers + reload the page. Noone of this is happening.

If client is not opening dev tools , old service worker is still giving an old api url.

**How to reset all cache and service worker in all my clients ?**

Comment: You can change the version of ngsw config. If it not helps return 404 for ngsw json. Refer this document. https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#app-versions

Comment: Andrius - did you find a solution for this, I'm seeing a similar issue

Comment: Nope, dont really understand how this caching works.

Comment: As Casperon stated, you need to add the `"version"` field to the [`ngsw-config.json`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/ngsw-config.json#L4) and possibly you may also need [this code snippet](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.component.ts#L87-L100) in the app.component.ts

Comment: I'm new to the service worker and found this link to be helpful. 
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications